# Using a GUID as entity Id vs the entity's "actual" Id

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In every cosmos db repository example I've seen, the id/row key has been generated like this: {partitionKey}:{Guid.newGuid()}. I'm working on a web api where the user won't necessarily have any way of knowing what this random GUID is. But they will know the EmployeeId, ProjectId etc. of the respective object, so I'm wondering if there are any issues with using i.e. EmployeeId as both the partition key and Id?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing technically wrong with the approach of setting id and partition key the same however you will have just one document per partition and that's bad design IMHO as all your read queries will be cross-partition queries (e.g. listing all employees).

One approach could be to set the partition key as the type of the entity (Employee, Project etc.) and then set the id as the unique identifier of the entity (employee id, project id etc.).

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, if you know the partition key AND the item id, you can do a Point read which is the fastest.
We used to also take the approach of using random guids for all item IDs, but this means you will always need to know this id and partition key. Sometimes a more functional key as the item ID makes more sense so have a good thought about it!
And remember, an item ID is not unique, the uniqueness is only within the partition key.
So you could have two items with the same item ID and different partition key.